# WIFI hotspot only running at 144mbps@5GHz but should be much faster Alfa Network AWUS1900

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, hot-spot, bandwidth

I own an Alfa Network AWUS1900 wireless adapter which I use to create a 5GHz hotspot in Ubuntu, which is running in VMWare Workstation under a Windows10-host, which both use the same network. The reason is to be able to connect my Oculus Quest VR-headset to stream my games via the 5GHz wifi from my computer to the Quest (which works perfectly) without the indirect way through my whole LAN & WLAN. (If someone has questions about that please check: "Virtual Desktop - Oculus Quest".)

So... the hotspot is working, I can connect all my wifi-devices and actually use them as I want BUT the wifi-bandwidth is stuck at only 144mbps @5GHz! The Alfa Network AWUS1900 supports up to 1300mbps over 5GHz (or at least way more than 144mbps... 867mbps should be realistic).

I tried several channels from 36(5.18 GHz) to 64(5.32 GHz) to 136(5.68 GHz) and nothing changed.
I disabled the power-saving-mode of the device.

How can I unlock the full speed in linux/ubuntu?
I can't get it to work. What's the command to crank up the speed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your wireless MTU? It should be 1492. `ip link` will show it. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: Well the MTU was 1500 and I now changed it to 1492 but this did not affect the low bandwitdh.

Comment: I think the adapter is only using wifi-n and not wifi-ac. How can I enable wifi-ac?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's me again.
I couldn't do it with Linux (Ubuntu & Kali) so I thought about something else.

Somewhere I read that the windows hotspot limitations came with an update some time ago. These limitations are the reason why the hotspot in default starts as 2.4GHZ, or if maybe in 5.0GHz, then limited to 144Mbps - 173Mbps max. It's not possible to create a 5GHz full-speed hotspot.

So what I did was:

- grabbed Windows 10 - version 1903 (that is the latest working I heard!!)
- installed it on a VM with VMware Workstation (3GB RAM, 2 Cores, USB3.0, minimalistic)
- keep internet disabled until the last step!!
- disabled everything that's unnecessary
- set network to bridged --> BUT DID NOT TURN IT ON!!!
- disabled windows update (via gpedit and services)
- disabled automatic driver installation
- decrapified windows via "Windows 10 Decrapifier"
- installed windows 10 driver for AWUS1900 / RTL8814AU from the dvd
- CREATED SNAPSHOT OF THE VM (saved checkpoint)
- enable ethernet
- connect AWUS1900 via VM hotplug
- connect to any (at best 5GHz) wifi (create hotspot with smartphone if necessary) --> other wise it will only create a 2.4GHz wifi... if already connected to another wifi it will create a 5GHz hotspot
- don't enable hotspot yet
- go to hotspot settings
- set up hotspot with SSID and password
- enable hotspot
- disconnect wifi (recommended because it's not needed anymore)

--> check hotspot with other devices, it will run with full-speed (in my case 867mbps)
(if not try again, it can be a pain in the ass, also check out nearby wifi frequencies and check if something is on the same channel as your hotspot, this can cause it to limit speed [I had to switch my fritzbox-channel from 60 to 40 because they were both on 60]!)

- minimize the VM, so it will run in background
- connect Oculus Quest with the wifi-hotspot (it shows 867mbps, full speed)
- launch VirtualDesktop on PC and Quest

--> Through bridged connection the Quest is in the same LAN as the PC and has direct access to VirtualDesktop with minimal latency and maximum bandwidth. It works just as good or even better than via a wifi-router. I just played some shooters in VR via VD and it works perfectly. Super low latency!

CHECK PICTURES/SCREENSHOTS:

[Wifi Analyzer - Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMIU0.jpg)

[inside VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZgCC.jpg)

[inside VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g47wB.jpg)

[View from other windows PCs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10kLI.jpg)